# Pyspark Read only One Element from Arrary of Struct

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an column which is of array type of Struct element.

```
|-- id
|-- paintUsed: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- paintCode: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- amountUsed: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- amount: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- unit: string (nullable = true)
```

Below is example of the data

```
id | PaintUsed
 ----------------------
 1  | [[Red,[ML, 100.0]],[Green[Litre, 4.0]]]
 2  | [[Blue,[ML, 400.0]],[Red[Litre, 2.0]]]
```

I Understand we can explode and get each of the element of struct as various rows, however my data volume is quite high and if i explode the number of rows will become 4-5 times and cause performance issue. From the above list I want to fetch the green colour value. This will only be one record and hence the number or records will not increase. I can explode and filter, but here before filter is applied the number of records will be too high.

Is there anyway to get only one element of a array of struct without explode.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: spark version ??, try higher order functions  or udf for this use case.

Comment: spark 2.6 UDF is a option but it would make the performance a slow. Udf will unpack and filter and return the element. But the performance will be slower than if i Explode to multiple rows and then filter thats what my gut feeling says

Comment: udf or HF is faster than exploding..  In exploding you are directly exploding column values into multiple rows, need to filter to get desired result, then you need to use groupBy to get distinct result, where as in udf will only work on that column value with filter & return required values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before **`explode`**, use higher order function **`filter`** on column **`paintUsed`**, to get only where **`paintUsed.paintCode='Green'`**.

```
df.withColumn("green", F.explode(F.expr("""filter(paintUsed, x-> x.paintCode == 'Green')""")))
```